# Hide a column while exporting to excel from datatable in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel

I want to hide a column while exporting from datatable to excel. Here is my code

```
`Dim xapp As Application
 Dim xWb As Workbook
fileName = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName & ".xls"
 fileName = fileName.Replace(".tmp", "")
 xapp = New Application()
 xWb = xapp.Workbooks.Open(fileName)
 xWb.Sheets(2).Columns("I:I").EntireColumn.Hidden = True`
```

Even though I mention the code to hide the column, still it is appearing in the excel while execution. Please help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The code looks correct to hide a column.  Are you certain that sheet `2` is the one with the column to hide?  If so, I think you will need to add some information about what you expect to happen and what is actually happening.

Comment: Yes the column in sheet2 is the column I need to hide. May I know what additional information you are talking about?

Comment: Is `sheet2` the same as `Sheet(2)`?  It's possible that the order of sheets does not match their names.  Is the column being hidden on some other sheet maybe?  The problem is that your code appears to have no issues.  I would expect it to work as written.  Since you believe it is not working, can you provide a picture (or a link to a picture on imgur or somewhere) with before/after?

Comment: I don't see it in your code, but make sure that your xWB is set to the workbook, perhaps that's causing an issue if you have more than one workbook open. Maybe `Set xWB = activebook` after the `...xapp.Workbooks.open(fileName)`

Also, I believe that using `Sheets(2)` will look at the spreadsheet second to the left, which may not necessarily be the same as `Worksheets("Sheet2")`.  Could that be an issue?

Comment: @user3578951, I don't think the `Set` is required in vb.net.  The assignment is made in the 2nd to last line on the `Open` call.